# "Application Error" on migrating Parse to Heroku

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

Because Parse is shutting down, I am migrating an existing Parse application into Heroku. I am following the steps listed here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Configuring-a-Parse-Server#testing-deployment

However, when I test deployment, I always get this error:

[image]

It's the same whether I use other tutorials. I have entered a `APP_ID` and `MASTER_KEY` but the problem is still there. Is there something I could have missed?

**Error Log**

```
2016-02-25T06:52:03.953554+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2016-02-25T06:52:05.303767+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-77-generic
2016-02-25T06:52:05.304153+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-02-25T06:52:05.304411+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.6.0
2016-02-25T06:52:05.304806+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
2016-02-25T06:52:05.305100+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-02-25T06:52:05.305271+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.1.0 start: `node index.js`
2016-02-25T06:52:05.305423+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-02-25T06:52:05.305594+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-02-25T06:52:05.305757+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.1.0 start script 'node index.js'.
2016-02-25T06:52:05.305918+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-02-25T06:52:05.306073+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the parse-server-example package,
2016-02-25T06:52:05.306231+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-02-25T06:52:05.306380+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-02-25T06:52:05.306529+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node index.js
2016-02-25T06:52:05.306677+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-02-25T06:52:05.280473+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/requiredParameter.js:8
2016-02-25T06:52:05.280468+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-02-25T06:52:05.280474+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw errorMessage;
2016-02-25T06:52:05.306835+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs parse-server-example
2016-02-25T06:52:05.307014+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-02-25T06:52:05.280478+00:00 app[web.1]: You must provide a serverURL!
2016-02-25T06:52:05.280474+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^
2016-02-25T06:52:05.307138+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-server-example
2016-02-25T06:52:05.295814+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-02-25T06:52:05.307269+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-02-25T06:52:05.310942+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-02-25T06:52:05.310734+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-02-25T06:52:05.311092+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-02-25T06:52:05.900578+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-02-25T06:52:05.918417+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: check your logs with `heroku logs` - that should show the stack trace.

Comment: `2016-02-25T06:52:05.280478+00:00 app[web.1]: You must provide a serverURL!` looks like the problem. Did you install the parse-server-example from the Deploy to Heroku button on https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example - I know that works.

Comment: Oh, that button works now. I might have put in the wrong SERVER_URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to enter a `SERVER_URL` or entered the wrong one. It should be `https://(appname).herokuapp.com/(parsemount)`

So if the App Name is `abc` and PARSE_MOUNT is `/parse`, the SERVER_URL is `https://abc.herokuapp.com/parse`